# Javascript loop inside a loop with if statement

Tags: javascript, loops

```
var jaar = 2014 ; 
var dagen = new Array("maandag ", "dinsdag ", "woensdag ", "donderdag ", "vrijdag ", "zaterdag ", "zondag ");
var dag = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]


document.write("<h2>januari</h2> <br> <br>");
for(i = 0 ; i < dagen.length ; i++)
{

    document.write(dagen[i]);

     if( i == 2)
    {
        for(x = 0 ; x < dag.length ; x++)
        document.write(dag[x])
    }
    else()
    {
    }    

}
```

For some reason my script isnt working, what i wanna do is that my second loop runs when my first loop is at his 2 array point. and i also want that my second loops runs one time. can someone help me ?

Comment: Just delete the `else` part and try again, in case of error, quote the error in your question.

Answer (score 1):

`else ()` will cause the syntax error. If you would like to check some condition in `else` condition, then use

`else if(some condition){
 }`

or simply use

```
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code. Please run the code given below.

```
var jaar = 2014 ; 
var dagen = new Array("maandag ", "dinsdag ", "woensdag ", "donderdag ", "vrijdag ", "zaterdag ", "zondag ");
var dag = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]


document.write("<h2>januari</h2> <br> <br>");
for(i = 0 ; i < dagen.length ; i++)
{

    document.write(dagen[i]);

     if( i == 2)
    {
        for(x = 0 ; x < dag.length ; x++)
        document.write(dag[x])
    }
    else
    {
    }    

}
```